# FileSystemWatcher Exception - The network BIOS command limit has been reached

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-service

I have tried asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811363/filesystemwatcher-exception-the-network-bios-command-limit-has-been-reached) on Stackoverflow, considering it is related to programming, but it appears it is more of a server issue than anything.

I have .Net framework 3.5 based application on Windows Server 2008, which is monitoring 22 folders on a remote server/network path. I am using `FileSystemWatcher` and every now and then I will get an exception in the log.

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network BIOS command limit has been reached.

I have tried following the [article KB-810886](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810886), but since my server is Windows Server 2008 I don't have registry keys for `MaxCmds`, `MaxMpxCT` etc. I have already looked at related questions on Stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065034/c-sharp-service-the-netwerk-bios-command-limit-has-been-reached-error-why-and) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050656/the-network-bios-command-limit-has-been-reached), but none of them seems to have resolved the issue.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to increase the limit of MaxCMDs in Windows Server 2008 ? **and** Do I have to increase the limit on my server hosting Windows Service, or should I increase the limit on the File Server (which has all the folders).

Here are coding things I have tried in my code:

I have tried increasing the [InternalBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to MAX (64K) but it doesn't have any effect on the exception.

I have defined it like:

At Class level:

```
FileSystemWatcher fsw;
```

In Initialization method

```
fsw = new FileSystemWatcher("FolderUNC");
fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
//m_fsw.InternalBufferSize = 65536; -- Commented out to default 8K
fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size;
fsw.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnFileSystemWatcherError);
fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

I am also making sure that I dispose the `FileSystemWatcher` object on Error or on stopping the service. Like

```
if (fsw != null)
    fsw.Dispose();
```

Any help or guidance in resolving the issue is appreciated.